# Popup HTML to last viewed page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am making an Chrome extension. I'm not an coding expert, but I understand the basics of html, css, and how to make an chrome extension.

I have an popup html, and I want to reference to other html pages, but every link will open in a new tab. I searched all over the internet, but I couldn't figure out how. When the popup is open on another page, and it closes, I want it to open on the same page. Is there an way, and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have a detailed context from your question, I'm gonna suggest you use `<iframe>` tag offered by HTML in order to load the desired page inside the popup

here's some useful reference
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP